# Android RecyclerView cells always left justified when using GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, centering, gridlayoutmanager

When using a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`, my cells are always left justified:  the free space always appears on the right side of the cell.  Using `ItemDecoration` to calculate offsets only makes the cells smaller, maintaining the free space to the right of the cells.  `gravity="center"` in the `RecyclerView` and `layout_gravity="center"` in the cells doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much banging my head against the wall, it turned out that the problems was using a fixed size for the cell.  By setting `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in the cell, things began behaving correctly and the `ItemDecoration` correctly applied the spacing.  I also removed `columnWidth="@dimen/[n]dp"`, although I haven't tested to see if that was necessary.

Comment: Thanks for this! Had the same issue =)